# What's the meaning of 'a big' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I cannot determine the meaning of 'a big' in the following paragraph about pregnancy. Please help me figure out what it means.

> But especially now, as a growing belly translates to feeling more
>   tired and achy, sex may become less and less desirable as your
>   pregnancy drags on. But other women report ***a big***
>   "can't-get-enough" surge in their third trimester -- so if you're one
>   of 'em, more power to you!

Comment: The *can't-get-enough sex* surge, which some women report experiencing in their third trimester, is big. **a big** means what **a big** always means, there is nothing out of the ordinary in the usage.

Comment: Big modifies surge in this example. ... women report a big ... surge ...

Answer (score 2):

In your example

> a big

and

> "can't-get-enough"

are adjectives for the type of "surge" that occurs, the first is magnitude/size, the second is type.  The same as in

> a big, frosty, cold beer

"A big" is the size and "frosty, cold" is the type of beer.